# Spring Security SpEL error in @Query of Spring Data JPA for new Role:Ordinal parameter not bound : 3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

Original query which works fine:

```
 String authorizeQuery = " and e.id in (select emp.id from Employee emp, Employee loggedIn where " +
            " 1 = ?#{hasAuthority('ADMIN') ? 1: 0} or 1 = ?#{hasAuthority('OPERATOR') ? 1: 0} or (loggedIn.oauthUser.id = ?#{principal.id} " +
            " and loggedIn.id in (emp.id, emp.lead.id, emp.team.leader.id)))";
```

I tried to add another role: `SUPER_ADMIN` in authentication like below:

```
String authorizeQuery = " and e.id in (select emp.id from Employee emp, Employee loggedIn where " +
            " 1 = ?#{hasAuthority('ADMIN') ? 1: 0} or 1 = ?#{hasAuthority('OPERATOR') ? 1: 0} or 1 = ?#{hasAuthority('SUPER_ADMIN') ? 1: 0} or (loggedIn.oauthUser.id = ?#{principal.id} " +
            " and loggedIn.id in (emp.id, emp.lead.id, emp.team.leader.id)))";
```

`authorizedQuery` is being used here:

```
@Query("select e from MyModel e " +
          " where " +
          " e.isActive=1 and "+
          " (:fieldOne is null or e.fieldOne = :fieldOne) and " +
          " (:fieldTwo is null or e.fieldTwo= :fieldTwo) " + authorizeQuery)
   Page<MyModel> searchAllMyModel(@Param("fieldOne") String fieldOne,
                                    @Param("fieldTwo") String fieldTwo, Pageable pageRequest);
```

When I request with this change, I get this error:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Ordinal parameter not bound : 3; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: Ordinal parameter not bound : 3

I have that role present in my associated Table.

Comment: Which version of spring-boot, spring-data-jpa are you using? found a bug in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1779 which seems like the one you have in spring-data-jpa `2.1.2`.

Comment: `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>` this one

Comment: Well try upgrading :)

Comment: do I need to d anything rather than upgrading the version? Just upgrading will do it?

Comment: Don't know it depends on your project, however it is very easy to bump up some version numbers in your pom.xml and try it on your own. Latest stable is `2.5.5`

Comment: It worked updating the version with tweaking a little bit of security config. Thanks